# ios: NSLog show decimal value

Tags: ios, nslog, nsdecimalnumber

```
NSNumber *weekNum = [dictionary valueForKey:@"inSeasonFor"];
NSDecimalNumber *newWeekNum = ([weekNum intValue]  *2)/4;
NSLog(@"%", [newWeekNum decimalValue]);
```

How can I divide weekNum*2 by 4 and keep the decimal value and print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want the fractional part as well, right?

```
NSNumber *weekNum = [dictionary valueForKey:@"inSeasonFor"];
// multiplication by 2 followed by division by 4 is division by 2
NSLog(@"%f", [weekNum intValue] / 2.0f);
```

//we can also use intfloat to resolve.